# Azure - create vm with ssl public key programmatically

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

[image: Create VM ssh public key]

I'm trying to create a virtual machine programmatically with ssh public key using azure java SDK. 
I saw the [create vm example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/examples/VMCreateGuide/src/main/java/VMCreateGuide.java) and there we can see:

```
request.getOsProfile().setAdminUsername(adminUsername);
request.getOsProfile().setAdminPassword(adminPassword);
```

My question is - what should I set to this OsProfile in order to create a VM with the SSH public key from the attached image?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `LinuxConfiguration` property in `OSProfile`. Here is the sample code:

```
// Set up SSH public key
String fullStorePath = " ~/.ssh/authorized_keys";
String sshKeyData = "you-ssh-key-data";

SshPublicKey sshPublicKey = new SshPublicKey();
sshPublicKey.setPath(fullStorePath);
sshPublicKey.setKeyData(sshKeyData);

// SShConfiguration
ArrayList<SshPublicKey> keyList = new ArrayList<SshPublicKey>();
keyList.add(sshPublicKey);

SshConfiguration sshConfig = new SshConfiguration();
sshconfig.setPublicKeys(keyList);

// Linux Configuration
Bool shouldDisablePasswordAuthentication = False;
LinuxConfiguration linuxConfig = new LinuxConfiguration();
linuxConfig.setSsh(sshConfig);
linuxConfig.setDisablePasswordAuthentication(shouldDisablePasswordAuthentication);

// set your OSProfile now
request.getOsProfile().setLinuxConfiguration(linuxConfig);

// you code goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the property `linuxConfiguration` of the request json body for the REST API [`Create or update a VM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163591.aspx), as @Steven said, it's correct and great for setting the [`SshConfiguration`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/models/SshConfiguration.html) & [`LinuxConfiguration`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/models/LinuxConfiguration.html) for [`OSProfile`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/models/OSProfile.html).

Thanks for Steven's sharing.